# How to cancel Close event of Microsoft.Ui.Xaml.Window?

Tags: c#, winui-3

Previously I built my program using System.Windows.Window, and I could cancel the window closing event by overriding the OnClosing event so that the window could only be closed through the tray menu.
However, when I tried to use the WinUI3 template to build the program, this functiona didn't seem to work, because the template was implemented using WindowEx, which inherits Microsoft.Ui.Xaml.Window, and I really couldn't prevent the window before calling the Closing event.
How can I deal with that?
This is the codes of MainWindow.

```
public sealed partial class MainWindow : WindowEx (WindowEx : Microsoft.Ui.Xaml.Window)
{
    private readonly Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue dispatcherQueue;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AppWindow.SetIcon(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Assets/WindowIcon.ico"));
        Content = null;
        Title = "AppDisplayName".GetLocalized();

        // Theme change code picked from https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/pull/1239
        dispatcherQueue = Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread();
    }

    // this handles updating the caption button colors correctly when indows system theme is changed
    // while the app is open
    private void Settings_ColorValuesChanged(UISettings sender, object args)
    {
         This calls comes off-thread, hence we will need to dispatch it to current app's thread
        dispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(TitleBarHelper.ApplySystemThemeToCaptionButtons);
    }
    // ovverride OnClosing ?!
}
```

I just want my program running in background and can only be closed through the tray menu.

Comment: This might do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/74745163/403671

Comment: Yes. It could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have [WinUIEx](https://github.com/dotMorten/WinUIEx/blob/main/docs/concepts/WindowExtensions.md#:%7E:text=()%3B-,myWindow.Hide()%3B%60,-Move%20and%20resize) installed, you can use the `Hide()` extension method.

```cs
pubilc MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Closed += MainWindowClosed;
}

private void MainWindow_Closed(object sender, WindowEventArgs args)
{
    // Keep the closed event from going deeper.
    args.Handled = true;
    // Hide the current window.
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: After adding a flag variable, I could realize my function. A good resolution!